# Update Parent Component State from Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setting a state into child component on event perform and want to sent this to Parent component. I searched for this on SO. But still didn't found any way to do this.

Let say i have a **parent** component  **Home**, and have **child** component  **User**. I am performing some event in **User** component, and at that time, i want to pass data to **Home** component. How can i do this?

**Below is my code:**

```
/* Parent component */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import User from './user';

class Home extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
           isReportSent: false
        }   
    }
    render(){
        <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/" component={User}/>
        </Switch>
    }
}

/* child component */
class User extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render(){

    }
}
```

**Note**: My parent component is Routing component, in which i am routing my child component on particular path. So can't pass any function to child component.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `render` props in Routes to pass callback method to child which you can then use to update the parent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import User from './user';

class Home extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
           isReportSent: false
        }   
    }
    performUpdate = () => {

    }
    render(){
        <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <User {...props} performUpdate={this.performUpdate}/>}/>
        </Switch>
    }
}

/* child component */
class User extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    handleClick=() => {
       this.props.performUpdate(); //call to inform parent about change
    }
    render(){

    }
}
```

Comment: I think this should be accepted has answer, this is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will let you know once test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pass a method, you just need to use the render prop

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" render={(props)=><User {...props} someMethod={someMethod} />}/>
</Switch>
```